# How to Re Deploy app after making certain changes on firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have deployed my `Reactjs` Application with firebase but After making certain changes to my code, I want to redeploy that app. How can I redeploy the app after making changes to my code?

I follow these steps to deploy:

1. Firebase login
2. firebase init (follow the procedure and create **build**)
3. npm run build
4. firebase deploy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply run `firebase deploy` again from the same folder where you ran `fireabse init`.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, you have to build the new changes.

   `npm run build`
2. Then `Firebase deploy` to deploy the app

You should run these two commands inside your project folder where you ran `firebase init`.

Answer (score 0):

on the root of your project first, you have to run `npm run build` then `firebase deploy`